# javaFX Storing number format in label or spinner

Tags: java, javafx, binding, spinner

I have a tableview, in one of his columns i calculate the subTotal:
Column "subTotal" = "Qty * price", after calculating the subtotals, i calculate the sum of all subtotals.
Maybe using: 
- a label,So How i can store and retrieve the sum from a  label as needed.
- Spinner, So How to bind the sum to the Spinner's valueProperty.

Here is the first option using a label:

```
 DoubleBinding doubleBinding = Bindings.createDoubleBinding(() -> tableView.getItems().stream().
                collect(Collectors.summingDouble(LineCommand::getSubTotal)), tableView.getItems());
        lblTotalHt.textProperty().bind(Bindings.format("%3.2f", doubleBinding));
```

The problem how i can retreive the stored sum ?

the second option:
How to perform this using a spinner

```
fldTotalHt.valueProperty().....Bind(toTheSum);
```

Comment: `doubleBinding.getValue()` will give you the sum.

Comment: but i need an obvervable value not the value

Comment: Uh, `doubleBinding` *is* an `ObservableValue`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question: "How can I retrieve the stored sum?", you can get this from the binding with

```
double sum = doubleBinding.getValue();
```

For the second question, you can do

```
Spinner<Double> spinner = new Spinner(min, max, doubleBinding.getValue());
spinner.getValueFactory().valueProperty().bind(doubleBinding.asObject());
```

(`asObject()` effectively converts the `ObservableValue<Number>` to an `ObservableValue<Double>`).

But note that binding a spinner's value is pretty pointless. A bound value cannot be set, for obvious reasons, so the user would not be allowed to change the value of the spinner - this means it would have no more functionality than a label. It's really not clear *why* you would want to display this value in a spinner, since it really doesn't make any sense for the user to be able to change a value which is computed from other values. Why not just use a label?

Comment: it works, but i get an exception: Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: DoubleSpinnerValueFactory.value : A bound value cannot be set.
 at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(ObjectPropertyBase.java:142)
 at javafx.scene.control.SpinnerValueFactory.setValue(SpinnerValueFactory.java:152)

Comment: I already address that in the question: you can't set a bound value. I cannot understand why you would use a spinner for this, because it makes no sense for the user to be able to change the value. A value that is computed from other values should be displayed in a non-editable control, such as a label.

Comment: because i need to to calculate other thing based on that spinner. spinner.valueProperty() is better than (Double.parseDouble(label.getText()); so what's your opinion ?

Comment: Why are you trying to get the data from the control? You *already have an `ObservableValue` with the sum in it*; you don't need to ask the spinner for the value or the label for the value. Just get it from the `doubleBinding`.

Comment: i need some thing like this : doubleBinding.multiply(VATSpinner.valueProperty().divide(100)); I hope this clarify things a little.

Comment: OK, so why don't you do exactly that?

Comment: there is no VATSpinner.valueProperty().divide(doubleNumber); i need to access divide function like doubleBinding.divide(someProperty);

Comment: OK, so all you have to do is convert a `ReadOnlyObjectProperty<Double>` to a `DoubleExpression` of some kind. There are a ton of ways to do that, just read the java docs.

Comment: I got the idea, Thank's for clarifing, I'm a litlle bit confused about javaFX properties and Bindings. So, It work now. doubleBinding.multiply(DoubleExpression.doubleExpression
                            (fldTVA.valueProperty()).divide(100))));

Answer (score 1):

If `fldTotalHt` is a `Spinner`, then you can access its value property like this

```
fldTotalHt.getValueFactory().valueProperty().bind(sumProperty)
```

About a label. I don't quite understand, what you really what. As I understood, you just can't get label's contents. But that's simply `label.getText()` and it's strange if you know about properties and bindings, but don't know about that.

Comment: i need to extract label.getText in double format, i tried to get it using Double.parseDouble(label.getText()); but i got numberFormatException

Comment: About fldTotalHt.getValueFactory().valueProperty().bind(sumProperty), i really have doubleBinding but i don't know how to convert it to fit .bind(doubleBinding ). I hope you understand me

Comment: About NumberFormatException. Looks like your system locale uses commas instead of dots. Try adding `Locale.ENGLISH` as a first argument to `Bindings.format()`

Comment: If you make your spinner use `Number` instead of `Double` it will accept `DoubleBinding`. I'm thinking about better ways to do so, but that's what came to mind first.

Comment: So, `spinner.getValueFactory().valueProperty().bind(doubleBinding.asObject())` seems to work correctly

Comment: for the labdel "Locale.ENGLISH" Do the job. But for spinner.getValueFactory().valueProperty.bind(doubleBidng.asObject()); i get an exception : Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: DoubleSpinnerValueFactory.value : A bound value cannot be set.